# Laravel Auditing BadMethodCallException Method audits does not exist

Tags: laravel, audit, laravel-auditing

I'm using laravel auditing, [Link](http://laravel-auditing.com/docs/8.0/introduction)
and I have use it with my controller and it was working fine, now my problem is when I apply it to another controller is does work, is it only allowed to use once? my method all the same I'm just confuse why it doesn't work.

**First controller code** (WORKING FINE)

```
 $leads = Lead::findOrFail($id);
 $audit=Lead::findOrFail($id)->audits()->with('user')->get()->last();
```

**Second Controller code:** (Not Working Error: Method audits does not exist.)

```
  $scores = Score::with(['lead','subject'])->where(['subject_id'=>$id])->get();
  $audit = $scores->audits()->with('user')->get()->last();
```

Comment: Are you sure you have used "implements Auditable" on Score model ? Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Yes i have already implemented it inside my model,

Comment: check this http://www.laravel-auditing.com/docs/8.0/getting-audits , i dont see them using audits method on multiple records. Hope this is helpful.

Comment: i'm performing audit on the SCORE table only same with the Lead table there is no difference .. i don't understand why it complicates

Comment: get method fetches multiple rows

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what Laravel auditing is, but my good guess is, your first one is a object, so you can apply your audit() method on it directly, but the second one, $scores, is a collection of objects, you surely can not directly apply a method call on it, try to iterate it, should be fine.